# Java: log4j initialization error

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm new in using the log4j package and I don't see the error:
This is a very simple and straightforward code sample:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLogger {

    private static Logger logger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
        logger.info("Hello");

    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:129)    at
>   my.package.logging.TestLogger.main(TestLogger.java:15)

I am wondering what on earth it's all supposed to mean ...

Could you help here?

Comment: Which version of `log4j`are you using? Also post your `.properties` or `.xml` file

Comment: please read the http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html Next you will face missing Appenders.

Comment: I am using version 2.0-beta1 without a xml, i.e. it should handle it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most probably missing  one of the dependencies. This is easy reproducible if you only include in your classpath the `log4j-api-2.0-beta1.jar` file.

If you downloaded [the binary distribution](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/2.0-beta1/apache-log4j-2.0-beta1-bin.zip), include also the `log4j-core-2.0-beta1.jar` in your classpath.  If your using Maven, put this in your `pom.xml`:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Your are absolutely right. This error occurs when missing to add log4j-core to the referenced libraries! Now when I implemented my first basic xml, I am able to log. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by avoiding multiple copies on the classpath of the log4j2 jars.

The NPE occurs at Line 129 of LogManager.
(return statement = Line 129)

```
/**
 * Return a Logger with the specified name.
 *
 * @param name The logger name.
 * @return The Logger.
 */
public static Logger getLogger(String name) {

    return factory.getContext(LogManager.class.getName(), null, false).getLogger(name);
}
```

The Problem seems to be, that the factory (LoggerContextFactory) is null = not initialized.
Initialization takes place in a static initializer block in the class LogManager.

My assumption is, that initialization failes when there is more than one LogManager on the classpath.

In my project (a webapplication developed with eclipse) i had the jars in my WEB-INF/lib *and* referenced by a dependency to another project.
Making ALL references point to the same jars solved that issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me (updated: now the same as your original posting, but showing the imports)

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLogger
{
    private static Logger logger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
        logger.info("Hello");
    }
}
```

provided that you have created a log4j configuration, otherwise you'll get the dreaded error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (TestLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: This code is direcly adopted from http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html. Logger hasn't a function like this anymore. Probably in log4j.v1

Comment: OK - but I have just tried both versions (Logger and LogManager) and both versions work for me.

Comment: ok. I added the imports. Since I am using the **log4j-api2.0-beta1** package, there is another package reference org.apache.logging.log4j instead of org.apache.log4j as in the log4j12 package

Comment: Ah, that might explain it - I am using 1.2.16

Comment: Anyways, i tried to use 1.2 and got a java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:203)

Comment: Odd - I just created a fresh Eclipse project with nothing but a) the sourcecode listed in my answer b) `log4j-1.2.16.jar` and c) a `log4.properties` file - and it works...

Comment: well probably this is the problem. I don't have a log4.properties or an xml file. Hence, it should handle it by default without a nullpointer exception, right? Can't find a nice documentation for that...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You are totally right with your answer but in my case there was another solution by implementing the core library.