# NPE when using log4J-2.0-beta

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am checking out log4j2 via the [overview documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html#Overview) and I am getting the following exception when trying to setup the log4j2 logger:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:129)
    at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:5)
```

My test program is taken from the overview site:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I added all the provided jar files from the [binary distribution](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/download.html) to my build path.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764362/java-log4j-initialization-error

Comment: @anarinsky The issue occurs with the entire binary distribution added as referenced libraries - this includes api, core, etc. If I remove the javadoc and sources jars, my output is null but no NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't! Use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) instead of Log4J!

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea this existed!

Comment: Spread the word then! Logback is written by the very same person who wrote Log4J.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumble across this in the future:

JAR `log4j-core-2.0-beta2-sources` is the cause of the error. If you remove this JAR from your build path you can build properly.

I opened up a JIRA ticket on the ASF tracker located at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-118 regarding this issue.