# log4j null pointer exception in spring and log4j example

Tags: spring, log4j, nullpointerexception

I am trying yo include log4j in my spring example.
However, when I tried as

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class);
```

I got the error as

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:203)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger$PrivateManager.getContext(Logger.java:61)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:43)
at core.MainApp.<clinit>(MainApp.java:11)
Exception in thread "main"
```

MainApp.java file :

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class MainApp {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {




      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");


       log.info("Going to create HelloWord Obj");

       HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

       obj.getMessage();

       log.info("Exiting the program");

}
}
```

I have also kept my log4j.properties file in my class path.
I think I have also initialized my log4j.
My beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="helloWorld" class="core.HelloWorld">
   <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>

<bean id="log4jInitializer">
<property name="staticMethod">
    <value>org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging</value>
</property>
<property name="arguments">
     <list>
        <value>log4j.properties</value>
     </list>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

My log4j.properties file:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

Does any one know what the problem could be?
Greetings!

Comment: probably log4j is not initialzed. init it first

Comment: @AlexWien I think I have initialized it in my beans.xml. Just now, I have added my beans.xml file. Please have a look at it.

Comment: can you show your log4j properties file?

Comment: @RameshK I have added log4j.properties too..

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout can you move this line to first line... just give a try..

Comment: @RameshK I tried.. but getting the same null pointer exception

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764362/java-log4j-initialization-error? You may miss some dependencies.